# What are the white eggs growing from a black stem on the Napa cabbage plant?

Tags: species-identification, botany, entomology, mycology

Are they fungal or eggs?
Can't find anything like this in the internet

[image]

Location: South Florida

Comment: I believe those are fruiting bodies of a microorganism, probably either a fungus or a slime mold. I don't think they are eggs of an insect or other animal.  The oddest thing to me is the leaves are relatively healthy appearing yet there are dense stands of these bodies.  Perhaps it was feeding on something on the surface of the leaves rather than within the leaf tissue.

Comment: Related: [Tiny black mushrooms growing from veggies?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/110992/tiny-black-mushrooms-growing-from-veggies)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm no expert in [slime molds](https://ucmp.berkeley.edu/protista/slimemolds.html), but your specimens do in fact look a lot like the [sporangia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporangium), or spore-producing reproductive structures (i.e., [fruiting bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporocarp_(fungi))), of a [Mycetozoan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycetozoa) slime mold in the class [Myxogastria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myxogastria).  [***Physarum***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physarum) and [***Comatricha***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comatricha) are possible candidate genera based on structure of their sporangia that I can find easily online.

See below for an example image:

[image]

<sup>Sporangia of *Physarum pusillum*. Source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2014-05-19_Physarum_pusillum_(Berk._%26_M.A._Curtis)_G._Lister_421497.jpg)</sup>

You can see many photos of the white sporangia of *Physarum pusillum* [here](http://nathistoc.bio.uci.edu/Myxomycetes/Physarum%20pusillum.htm) and a close-up of the white sporangium of *Physarum pseudocolumellatum* [here](https://sarahlloydmyxos.wordpress.com/physarales/physarum-sporangia/)

I don't think I can provide a more specific answer given the quality of your photo or my general lack of deeper knowledge of these organisms. Regardless, no quick search for slime-mold infections in plants produced any information regarding slime mold species that regularly grow above-ground on cabbage.

- However, I did find [this site](http://extension.msstate.edu/publications/the-plant-doctor-slime-molds) which suggests that decreasing the moisture or increasing the salinity of the slime mold's environment will cause it to [move along](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GY_uMH8Xpy0)...