# Tiny black mushrooms growing from veggies?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

[image]

I've found these tiny black mushrooms sprouting from my scallions.  I'm in Salt Lake, UT, but the scallions are store-bought, so I'm not sure where they're from or where they've been. Anyone know what these are?  Are they dangerous?

Comment: Related: [What are the white eggs growing from a black stem on the Napa cabbage plant?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/89273/16866)

Comment: @theforestecologist that looks spot on.  I flagged my question as a duplicate